# Filtering Enteties in EF 6.0 with WPF and MySql

Tags: c#, mysql, wpf, entity-framework, linq

Hi I am doing my first EF and MySql project in WPF

I have an Entity called Staff which is the staff table from the MySql database, part of the record is an "isactive" flag which can be 1 or 0 (zero being Left)

I have done a combo on this entity but it shows all the records in the database table when what I really want to see is the "active" staff, in SQL I would just do a `"where isactive=1"` clause

The auto generated code is

```
private System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<HelpdeskTickets.ost_staff> Getost_staffQuery(HelpdeskTickets.ostEntitiesv2 ostEntitiesv2)
        {
            // Auto generated code

            System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<HelpdeskTickets.ost_staff> ost_staffQuery = ostEntitiesv2.ost_staff;
            // Returns an ObjectQuery.
            return ost_staffQuery;
        }
```

I have tried a `return ost_staffQuery.Where("isactive=1");`
but this returns no results I feel I should have an object to filter or being doing something with LINQ

Can someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Where() method in Linq is used with a lambda like so:

```
 return ost_staffQuery.Where(staff => staff.isactive);
```

or alternately

```
 return ost_staffQuery.Where(staff => staff.isactive == true);
```

You say that when isactive is 0 it is Left, but I am not sure what that means.  Typically Entity Framework will work with bit (0/1) types as booleans.

Is there a reason that you cannot query from your context?  Something like:

```
myStaffContext.StaffMembers.Where(staff => staff.isactive).ToList();
```

Be advised that the Where() method will not actually return objects.  It returns an IQueryable.  To actually execute the query, you should do a ToList or other method that either returns single (First() or FirstOrDefault()) or IEnumerable types.

If you are returning numeric values, something like

```
.Where(staff => staff.isactive == 1);
```

Comment: Hi ther sorry for lack of clarity, the record returns the value 1 for the member of staff is active or 0 for the member of staff has left the compnay for the isactive field in the database, so I am thinking along the lines of

Comment: No problem. I added an answer that takes care of that situation too.

Comment: Hi just tried that with no luck but was trying to do on the context as the actual returned ost_staffQuery is the source CollectionViewSource so I believe I need objects returned to be used in the CollectionViewSource, should I be filtering the CollectionViewSource instead?

Comment: That kind of depends on how your project is set up and how difficult it is to get data out of your database.  If it takes longer than normal on each request to get data, I would say get more data on each turn around, and filter it in your application.  If you have good communication with the database and everything is humming along quickly, only get the data that you intend to display.  As to the context, is this a database first, code first, or model first EF project?

Comment: Data base first project. If I did this using old SQL I would have a Sql view and Data reader it into a list to act as the source of the combo but every thing I read says EF is a preferred method. Hence the need to learn it :-)

Comment: I have not used database first in years, but you should have a context class through which all of your EF communication goes.  This class is generated out of the edmx model file.  In that context class, you should have collection properties that correspond to each of your mapped tables.  Personally, I have left database first and started developing exclusively in Code First.  I have found that it provides me with much greater flexibility in regards to the topology of my database and model.